# how can I get one return value of array in nested loop with conditional in php?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, return-value, nested-loops

## How can I get one return value array from if else condition ?

**my code like this :**

```
function fitur_4($extract_fitur){
    $fiturempat=array();
    $data_kata3=$extract_fitur['data_kata3'];
    $data_total_kalimat=$extract_fitur['data_total_kalimat'];
    $data_kalimat=$extract_fitur['data_kalimat'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data_kata3) ; $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j<$data_total_kalimat[$i]; $j++) { 
            $start='“';
            $kata=explode(" ", $data_kalimat[$i][$j]);
            $tot_kata=count($kata);
            $end ='”';
            $pos = stripos($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $start);
            $str = substr($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $pos);
            $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
            $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);//hitung per karakter
            $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);//kata dalam petik dua
            $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces
            $pecah_unit=explode(" ",$unit);
            $tot_petik=count($pecah_unit);

            if(strpos($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $start)!==false){
                $fitur4= $tot_petik/$tot_kata;
                array_push($fiturempat, $fitur4);                       
            }else{
                // empty value must insert in array $fiturempat
            }
        }
        return $fiturempat;
    }
}
```

I want to get return value $fiturempat in array from (if & else condition).

Answer (score 0):

use array_push in else part too.

```
function fitur_4($extract_fitur){
    $fiturempat=array();
    $data_kata3=$extract_fitur['data_kata3'];
    $data_total_kalimat=$extract_fitur['data_total_kalimat'];
    $data_kalimat=$extract_fitur['data_kalimat'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data_kata3) ; $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j<$data_total_kalimat[$i]; $j++) { 
            $start='“';
            $kata=explode(" ", $data_kalimat[$i][$j]);
            $tot_kata=count($kata);
            $end ='”';
            $pos = stripos($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $start);
            $str = substr($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $pos);
            $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
            $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);//hitung per karakter
            $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);//kata dalam petik dua
            $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces
            $pecah_unit=explode(" ",$unit);
            $tot_petik=count($pecah_unit);

            if(strpos($data_kalimat[$i][$j], $start)!==false){
                $fitur4= $tot_petik/$tot_kata;
                array_push($fiturempat, $fitur4);                       
            }else{
                array_push($fiturempat, '');
            }
        }
        /// May be you need to push till both for loop end so moved down
    }
    return $fiturempat;
}
```

you can also conditional push for null checking.

Comment: did you tried 0 instead of '' in else part?.... or rather using push you can try $fiturempat[]=0; in else part

Comment: I have tried again, maybe my mistakes in return value, because there is in nested loop..how about you?, because i tried to use print_r, the value not empty, it means the value had succed to input..

Comment: Yes was assumed that and mentioned in my code with comment that you might need to return after both for loop :)

Comment: but I want it return just one array dimension, not two dimension or more..

Comment: it will return one dimension only!

Comment: I have tried to push as like your suggestion @paras pitroda but the result in array two dimensional array :)